# how to replace ID with name oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

i am currently working with 2 tables,
adverts and advert slots,

advert contains the attributes ad_name and ad_id

advert slots contains 6 columns, ad_1 - ad_6, each showing a different ad

is it possible to list the ads by name when printing out advert slots instead of the ad_id's

i will put below  what i have gotten so far, but instead of this listing the 24 ads i was expecting, it lists ads multiple times, up to 625 results

```
select * from
(select adverts.ad_name as ad_1 from adverts join ad_slots on ad_1 = 
adverts.ad_id),
(select adverts.ad_name as ad_2 from adverts join ad_slots on ad_2 =   
adverts.ad_id),
(select adverts.ad_name as ad_3 from adverts join ad_slots on ad_3 = 
adverts.ad_id),
(select adverts.ad_name as ad_4 from adverts join ad_slots on ad_4 = 
adverts.ad_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a series of `left join`s:

```
select s.*, a1.ad_name, a2.ad_name, a3.ad_name, a4.ad_name
from ad_slots s left join
     adverts a1
     on s.ad_1 = a1.ad_id left join
     adverts a2
     on s.ad_2 = a2.ad_id left join
     adverts a3
     on s.ad_3 = a3.ad_id left join
     adverts a4
     on s.ad_4 = a4.ad_id ;
```

Comment: thank you so much, not i have to go and learn where you managed to get s.* from, thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way?

```
select (select ad_name from advert where a.ad_1 = ad_id ) as 'ad_1',
(select ad_name from advert where a.ad_2 = ad_id ) as 'ad_2',
(select ad_name from advert where a.ad_3 = ad_id ) as 'ad_3',
(select ad_name from advert where a.ad_4 = ad_id ) as 'ad_4'
from ad_slots a
```

[image]